# Unable to add buttons to ActionBar dynamically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to add ActionBar buttons, but without having to create a separate .xml file for each activity. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.ic_refresh_str).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh);
        return true;
    }
```

The button does not appear. If I modify the code to the following code, it works:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.ic_refresh_munawwat).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return true;
    }
```

But the problem is that android:minSdkVersion is 7, and here is the error message that I get on setShowAsAction:

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7):
>   android.view.MenuItem#setShowAsAction

How can I add dynamically buttons and keep supporting minSdk 7?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try android-support-v4 library or [Actionbar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the deprecated function MenuCompat.setShowAsAction

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.ic_refresh_txt).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh);
        MenuCompat.setShowAsAction(item, 2);

        return true;
    }
```